# Background is repeating only on Chrome - even after adding 'no-repeat'

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background, background-image

I need find out why my background is repeating in my CSS even after using no repeat. I'm trying to avoid using background cover, as it distorts the image. This is *only* happening on Chrome.

https://natalyhelps.github.io/projects/inspiredquotes/inspiredquotes.html

I tried adding no-repeat. I tried putting my code through chatgpt. I tried checking the image URL. I tried accessing in different browsers. I tried recommitting different codebases.

```css
  body {
  background: url("http://natalyhelps.github.io/lotus.png");
  color: #5A5A5A;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
}

#quotecontainer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* White with 50% opacity */
  height: auto;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#quote {
  letter-spacing: 1.7px;
  font-family: cambria;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

#btn {
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* Add box shadow when button is pressed */
  color: #5A5A5A;
  border: solid 1px rgba(245, 93, 180, .9);
  /* Equivalent to #FF69B4 */
  ;
  ;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(248, 96, 180, .9);
  /* Equivalent to #FF69B4 */
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(245, 93, 180, 1);
  /* Equivalent to #FF69B4 */
  color: #5A5A5A;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  #output {}
```

```html
<div id='quotecontainer'>
  <div id='quote'>
    <button id='btn'>
      Press Me</button>
    <div id='output'>Press the button for wisdom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems fine in Chrome here. Cleared your cache?

Comment: Thank you for checking for me! 

I think cleared my cache effectively. I refreshed by using CTRL + F5. And then I went to Clear Browser Data(on Chrome) and clicked 'Clear cached images and files in the last 24hours.' (I only started working on this this morning) I restarted my computer in case it was a browser glitch.  

However, it is performing fine when it's open in an incognito tab via Chrome. It's performing as expected on Brave. It also performs fine when I open it on Chrome via codecademy workspaces. I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your extensions/addons/plugins and trying?

Comment: I doesn't look very good on small viewports, but whatever viewport size/aspect ratio I give it it doesn't repeat at all.

Answer (score -1):

html `code`

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id='quotecontainer'>
        <div id='quote'>
            <button id='btn'>

                Press Me</button>
            <div id='output'>Press the button for wisdom</div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<script src="inspiredquotes.js"></script>
```

```
CSS code

#container {
    background: url("http://natalyhelps.github.io/lotus.png");
    /* color: #5A5A5A; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This put the background in a different place, like a card style. But I really like how that looks too even though it wasn't what I was originally going for. Thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).